# How to use jest to test an asynchronous epic with axios-mock-adapter mock data?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, rxjs, jestjs, redux-observable

when I run testing code, actual$ returns an empty array, expected returns the mock data.
the reason is api.ugc.wishlist.getAllFolders() is asynchronous.
how should I write the test?

```js
//testing code:


describe('wishlist select', () => {
  describe('dispatch a correct action of load', () => {
    it('select getAllFolders successfully', () => {
      getTestScheduler().run(({ cold, expectObservable }) => {
        const action$ = ActionsObservable.from(
          cold('(a|)', {
            a: actions.load.start(),
          })
        );
        const state$ = new StateObservable<IState>(new Subject(), initialState);

        const expected$ = {
          a: actions.load.done(toFolders(select.items)),
        };

        const actual$ = load(action$, state$, dependencies);
        // the actual$ return an empty array.
        expectObservable(actual$).toBe('(a|)', expected$);
      });
    });
  });
});


// load epic code:

export const load: IEpic = (action$, state$, { api }) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.load.start.getType()),
    mergeMap(() => {
      return from(api.ugc.wishlist.getAllFolders()).pipe( // get mock dara from axios-mock-adapter 
        mergeMap(response => {
          const { items } = response.data;
          return of(actions.load.done(toFolders(items)));
        })
      );
    })
  );
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I didn't see any `MockStore.dispatch()`. Also, what if you replace `cold` with `hot` in `actual$`'s definition?

Comment: Thank you! I think I find the reason. Because `api.ugc.wishlist.getAllFolders()` is an axios request and return as a promise. 
Rxjs doc: You can't directly test RxJS code that consumes Promises or uses any of the other schedulers